# pseudo element css background overlays - causing weird line renderings

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Have a banner area with a background image, with a two pseudo class background overlays over it. It seems to cause some weird lines rendering on the overlays. It does look better on retina monitors, but would like a better fix.

Live link: http://dev.wonderjarcreative.com/sample-page/

html

```
<div id="featured-banner" class="featured-banner">
  <div class="featured-banner-background-wrap">
    <div class="featured-banner-background-image" style="background( the url ) center top / cover">
      <img src="the url">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="featured-banner-content">
    <div class="wrap">
      <!-- content -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.featured-banner {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    flex: 1;
}

.featured-banner-background-wrap,
.featured-banner-background-image {
    height: 100%;
}

.featured-banner:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #383838, rgba(56,56,56,0.6));
}

.featured-banner-background-image:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #3579f5, #760484);
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.featured-banner-background-image img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.featured-banner-content {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2rem 0;
    color: #fff;
}

.featured-banner-content > .wrap {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Any ideas to eliminate the render lines would be appreciated!

Comment: You can declare multiple backgrounds in css without pseudos, have you tried this route?

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple background gradients without pseudos, I've used a static image to give the container some height and width, but you can see both gradients working at the same time. Use rgba for colour opacity in the gradients (as you have for the black) for futher adjustments.

```css
.featured-banner {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

.featured-banner-background-wrap,
.featured-banner-background-image {
    height: 100%;
}

.featured-banner {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #383838, rgba(56,56,56,0.6)), linear-gradient(to bottom right, #3579f5, #760484);
}

.featured-banner-background-image img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.featured-banner-content {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2rem 0;
    color: #fff;
}

.featured-banner-content > .wrap {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="featured-banner" class="featured-banner">
  <div class="featured-banner-background-wrap">
    <div class="featured-banner-background-image" style="background( the url ) center top / cover">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/1500x1500">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="featured-banner-content">
    <div class="wrap">
      <p>Here's some banner content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```